# O iv utilizado em AES-CTR pode ser armazenado em claro?

Tags: segurança, criptografia

Pretendo utilizar a cifra AES em counter mode e não tenho a certeza se posso guardar o iv (nonce + counter) em claro.

Answer (score 1):

Um [artigo da Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Initialization_vector_.28IV.29) diz (a traducao é minha):

> Um vector de inicialização tem requisitos de segurança diferentes duma chave, portanto o IV não precisa de ser secreto. Contudo, na maioria dos casos, é importante que o vector de inicialização nunca seja reusado com a mesma chave.

Nao precisas de manter o iv em segredo, mas tens de garantir que é unico.